# NullPointerException Error when Reading an Array Element from a File - Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In my program, I create an attraction and fill out the number of ticket types, is title and cost, and then I exit the program and run it again.

I have a constructor that reads elements from a file. When I then try to read an array element, it gives me a `NullPointerException` error even though the element is not null.

When I comment out the code block below where the error is located, I get a `NumberFormatException` error instead for the input string, "Tour Only", so I know it's not null.

```
fileScanner.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < getTicketTypesNum(); i++)
    this.ticketTypeTitle[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
fileScanner.nextLine();
```

The code in full is below.

*Attraction.java*

```
// The constructor.
public Attraction(Scanner fileScanner) {
  ...

  // The data read before the error.
  fileScanner.nextLine();
  this.ticketTypesNum = Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.nextLine());
  fileScanner.nextLine();

  fileScanner.nextLine();
  for (int i = 0; i < getTicketTypesNum(); i++) {
    // Line where the error is located.
    this.ticketTypeTitle[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
  }

  fileScanner.nextLine();
  for (int i = 0; i < getTicketTypesNum(); i++)
     this.ticketTypeCost[i] = Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.nextLine());
  fileScanner.nextLine();

  ...
}


// Store the attraction information and write it to file.
public void writeData(PrintWriter pw) {
  ...

  pw.println("Number of Ticket Types:");
  pw.println(getTicketTypesNum());
  pw.println();

  pw.println("Ticket Titles:");
  for (int i = 0; i < getTicketTypesNum(); i++)
    pw.println(getTicketTypeTitle()[i]);
  pw.println();

  pw.println("Ticket Costs:");
  for (int i = 0; i < getTicketTypesNum(); i++)
    pw.println(getTicketTypeCost()[i]);
  pw.println();

  ...
}
```

If you need more code, I'll edit my question to include more.

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**

I tried commenting out the line where I had the error out and continued running the code, and I get a NullPointerException whenver I have to read an array element.

Comment: So the array is not initialised? Did you try to use the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sample program which works. You can try this and print your array.
Make sure you have this **scanner.hasNextLine()** check before getting the elements from file. Also, ideally your array size should be equal to number of occupied lines in file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileRead {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String array[] = new String[6];

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\text");

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
            int i =0;
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                array[i] = sc.nextLine();
                i++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    }

}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @TanviGarg! I didn't allocate memory, so that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Please upvote as well it it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul check `fileScanner.hasNextLine()` before using `fileScanner.nextLine()`

Comment: I have a while check elsewhere that checks that.

Comment: You should check before everytime you want to use.

Comment: Could you tell me why you are using fileScanner.nextLine(); before and after for loop?